# Member of in JPQL not translated into SQL exists clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, innodb, spring-data-jpa

Why does the **member of** in JPQL is translated into:  **(? IN ( select ...))**.

I created the following query in JPQL:

```
select  si
    from  ShoppingItem si
    join  si.owner u
    where  u = :owner
      and  :following member of u.followers"
```

The above query is translated into:

```
select  shoppingit0_.id ...
    from  shopping_item shoppingit0_
    inner join  user user1_ on shoppingit0_.owner_id=user1_.id
    where
       and  user1_.id=?
      and  **(? IN (
                SELECT  followers2_.id
                    from  following followers2_
                    where  user1_.id=followers2_.target_id)
             )** ...
```

My technology stack: Spring Data JPA, hibernate, InnoDB engine, MySQL DB...

As you can see the **member of** is getting "translated" into (? **IN** (select followers2_.id from following followers2_ where user1_.id=followers2_.target_id))

The [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html) gives advice to optimize the "in" Subqueries with "Exists" queries.
**My question** is: why does the member of is translated into **? in (select ...)**  and not into **exists select(...)** ?

Is there some possibility to tell hibernate to use "exists" instead of "in" in such a case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query:

```
select  si
from  ShoppingItem si
join  si.owner u
where  u = :owner
  and exists (select f from Following f where f.target = u and f = :following )
```